How do I configure with the DNS in AWS Route53
I recently transferred my domain from squarespace to aws and I might've done something wrong on the DNS side while transferring.
I already created a S3 bucket and uploaded my webpage files. I created 2 hosted zones for the S3 bucket, but when I try to go on the webpage, it gives me the error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, which makes me think I severely messed up the DNS while trying to transfer the domain to AWS.

What do you have in DNS, then? Have you tried checking using any DNS lookup tool?

If you wish to connect a custom domain name to an Amazon S3 bucket, follow the steps here: Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service

It sounds like you haven't successfully transferred the domain name. That error indicates the domain's DNS servers can't be found. Try using this tool to test the domain https://dnschecker.org/

It could be that you unsuccessfully transferred it, or it could be that you specified the wrong DNS records at the new registrar.  try whois domain.name  with your domain and make sure the nameservers shown are correct.  That will also help you verify which registrar is serving the domain.
